# Is there a way to convert a HashMap to JsValue without setting fields myself?

Tags: rust, webassembly

Is there a better way than iter to convert `HashMap` to `JsValue`?

```
let mut map = HashMap::new<String, String>();

// put stuff in the map...

let obj = js_sys::Object::new();
for (k,v) in map.iter() {
    let key = JsValue::from(k);
    let value = JsValue::from(v);
    js_sys::Reflect::set(&obj, &key, &value).unwrap();
}
JsValue::from(obj)
```

Comment: No, any implementation is going to either be recursive or is going to have its own stack inside the code. There's probably a proof of that which involves the pumping lemma, but intuitively, you have nested data, so you're going to have to do self-similar operations to get from format A to format B. That's what recursion is for.

Comment: Which "direction" are you converting? And is the hashmap flat, or are there nested hashmaps?

Comment: I edit describe, the original description was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Serializing and Deserializing Arbitrary Data Into and From `JsValue` with Serde](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.html) in the wasm-bindgen guide: you can convert any type that is `Serialize`-able with the help of the [serde-wasm-bindgen](https://crates.io/crates/serde-wasm-bindgen) crate:

Using it, your code would look like this:

```
serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&map).unwrap()
```

The guide lists another crate, [gloo-utils](https://crates.io/crates/gloo-utils), that offers similar functionality but communicates data differently over the Wasm/Javascript bridge.